# Finding the magnetic field of an arbitrary arrangement of current-carrying wires

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

For an arbitrary arrangement of current-carrying wire, I am trying to show that the Taylor expansion around $\vec{r} =0$ of a magnetic field $\vec{B}(\vec{r})$ is given by

\begin{align}
\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0I}{{4\pi}} \int d\vec{r}' \times \Big(\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}{{r}'^3}
-3\vec{r}'\frac{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}'}{r'^5}\Big).
\end{align}

From the Biot-Savart law, I know that

\begin{align}
\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{{\mu _0 I}}{{4\pi }}\int\frac{{d\ell' \times {\bf{\hat {\mathfrak{r}}}}}}{{\mathfrak{r}^2}}
\end{align}

where $\vec{\mathfrak{r}} = |\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|$.

Now, I know that I can change the integrand in the Biot-Savart law using the properties of cross products and the fact that $\hat{\mathfrak{r}}=\vec{\mathfrak{r}}/\mathfrak{r}$. This causes the integrand to simplify to

\begin{split}
\frac{{d\ell' \times {\bf{\hat {\mathfrak{r}}}}}}{{\mathfrak{r}^2}} & = \frac{1}{\mathfrak{r}^3}({d\ell' \times ({\bf{\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}}}))\\
& =({d\ell' \times {\vec{r}}})/\mathfrak{r}^3.
\end{split}

So now I am trying to do a Taylor expansion of this term so that will hopefully result in the first equation I wrote. However, I am not sure how to Taylor expand $\frac{1}{\mathfrak{r}^3}$. Looking at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_Cartesian_coordinates) for expansion in Cartesian coordinates, I feel like I am on the correct track. However, I cannot follow their example.

- How do they get the $v_\alpha(\mathbf{R}) \equiv\left( \frac{\partial v(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}) }{\partial r_\alpha}\right)_{\mathbf{r}= \mathbf0}=\frac{-R_\alpha}{{R^3}}$ calculation? What is $r_\alpha$?
- Am I on the right track, in general, for solving this problem? Does anybody have any ideas?